# Can I move to the start of the line on command-line mode?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

I would like to move to the start of the line on the command-line mode with Ctrl + a. Right now I have the following setting on my `~/.vimrc`, which is effective on insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-a> <Esc>I
inoremap <C-e> <Esc>A
```

Of course on the normal mode you can move using `0` and `$`.

At least on the command-line mode, I can move to the end of the line by Ctrl + e, but is it also possible to move to the start of the line, possibly with Ctrl + a?

Comment: `:cnoremap <c-a> <c-b>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In command line mode `<C-b>` is used to move to the beginning of the line [`:h c_CTRL-B`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-B)

So you can use

```
cnoremap <c-a> <c-b>
```

---

Note that I would argue that it is useful to learn to use `<c-b>`: `<c-a>` in command line mode insert all of the file names which match the pattern in front of the cursor which can be pretty useful. For example, in my home directory, I can type

```
:argadd .bash
```

Then when I type `<c-a>` the command line will become:

```
:argadd .bashrc .bash_aliases .bash_aliases_local .bash_history .bash_profile
```

And I can then edit all of these files.

To keep this feature you can also create the invert mapping:

```
cnoremap <c-b> <c-a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also the tips! But for me it is more comfortable to make the behavior of `<c-a>` aligned in all situations, as it is the default shortcut on most editors on macOS.

Comment: @Blaszard I understand that it is also the default behavior of most shells :)